# Transparent Background in Ruby Squib

Tags: ruby, squib

I'm using Squib to create an easier workflow for creating new cards for a game I'm making. Everything is working great however the image for the card back I'm using has rounded corners. This leads to a kind of "dead area" between the rounded part of the card image and the corner of the actual outputted (?) image. There is an option to make this a specific color, however I was wondering if there is any way to make it completely transparent. The docs don't mention anything about an alpha value. I could work around it by making my card image completely rectangular, however I really want to avoid that because it makes the cards look much different than I intend.

Comment: look at https://andymeneely.github.io/squib/doc/Squib/Deck.html#png-instance_method there is an alpha option, it may help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of v0.9, the `save_png` method supports a `trim` and `trim_radius` option so you can render some real-life looking cards but still maintain a bleed region around the edges of your cards.

Also, the background color of a Squib card by default is empty. Maybe just remove the `background color:` call for the card backs?

(Full disclosure: I'm the developer of Squib)

Comment: Not that I don't believe you (you built it) but the documentation for [Squib::Deck](https://andymeneely.github.io/squib/doc/Squib/Deck.html#save_png-instance_method) doesn't have it listed. It's there for `save_pdf` and `save_sheet` but isn't listed for `save_png`. However removing the `background color:` worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Guilty. Those options are new to v0.9, which I released last week. I had trouble posting the updated docs on GitHub pages and I'm still diagnosing the problem. Here's the original doc line in the Ruby that SHOULD be on the website: https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/blob/master/lib/squib/api/save.rb#L135